# align swf object to the left with 100% width

Tags: html, flash

i have a swf object in my page, and i want it to have 100%width (entire screen) but i want the swf to be aligned to the left. with the following code it gives me the 100%width but the swf is aligned to the center of the page, is there a way to change the alignment? thanks!

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://localhost/arquitectos/flsh/menu.swf?" height="120px" width="100%">
                <param value="http://localhost/arquitectos/flsh/menu.swf?" name="movie">
                <param value="bgcolor" name="">
                <param value="transparent" name="wmode">
                <param value="left" name="align"></object>
```

Comment: If the SWF spans the entire screen width, how can it be centered or aligned in either direction? Maybe put it somewhere we can look at it. It sounds like you need to move the content inside the SWF to the left.

Comment: http://www.plasticmails.net/arquitectos/ as you can see i want that menu aligned to the left (the swf is 800x120px) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<td align="left>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://localhost/arquitectos/flsh/menu.swf?" height="120px" width="800px">
                <param value="http://localhost/arquitectos/flsh/menu.swf?" name="movie">
                <param value="bgcolor" name="">
                <param value="transparent" name="wmode">
                <param value="left" name="align"></object>
</td>
```

Comment: You'll probably need to put a div wrapper around the SWF object then put some CSS on the div. You'll probably need something like width:800px; margin:0 auto; to make it work.